# Retrieve roster in node-xmpp

Tags: node.js, xmpp, node-xmpp

I'm having trouble understanding how to retrieve an XMPP roster (and eventually the presence state of each contact) in node-xmpp (GTalk account).

My example code can login and connect, but I'm a bit lost as to what to send and listen for:

```
var xmpp = require('node-xmpp')

jid = 'example@gmail.com'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

// Establish a connection
var conn = new xmpp.Client({
    jid: jid,
    password: password,
    host: 'talk.google.com',
    port: 5222
})

conn.on('online', function() {
    console.log('ONLINE')
    var roster = new xmpp.Element('iq', {
        type: 'get',
        from: jid,
        id: new Date().getTime()
    }).c('query', { xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster' })
    conn.send(roster) // Now what?
})

conn.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: And please don't just point me at raw XMPP - I am new to it and the examples are very unclear how I might use them via node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the structure of my roster query was wrong, this works correctly:

```
conn.on('online', function() {
  console.log('ONLINE')
  var roster = new xmpp.Element('iq', {
    id: 'roster_0',
    type: 'get'
  }).c('query', {
    xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'
  })
  conn.send(roster)
})
```